# Store \ in java string variable(Special Character)

Tags: java

## I want to store \ in a string variable #

String var= "\" ;

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String var="\"
        System.out.println(var);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String var="\\";
```

will give you the backslash you want

Answer (score 0):

From [Characters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html)

> A character preceded by a backslash (\) is an escape sequence and has special meaning to the compiler. The following table shows the Java escape sequences:
>
> \\    Insert a backslash character in the text at this point.

[image]

So in you case use below code:

```
String var = "\\";
```